# Linux/Kernel module: Can a driver be used by two user programs?

Tags: linux, flash, module, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I'm trying to develop a "virtual" video driver based on ViVi project example. It's virtual since it doesn't interact with any camera. It gets a video stream from a user program (C++) and also it acts as video driver for another user program (Flash) which displays the video stream.

So, if I have a /dev/video0. One program needs write frame to it and another reads one from. Is that possible?

I need this because Flash doesn't recognize this camera, so I use a virtual driver as a bridge from my grabber (which uses the real driver) and Flash.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There used the vloopback driver, which did exactly what you want to do. However, it wasn't part of the standard kernel. Some time ago, I wrote a library ([dv4linux](http://dv4l.berlios.de/) that intercepted libc read/writes to /dev/video to achieve something similar. The current version has serious issues with newer firefox's malloc handling, though. berlios.de may fo out of service soon.

Comment: Interesting because there is a fork updated up to kernel 3.0: https://github.com/umlaeute/v4l2loopback. I need to go through this and see examples. Thanks.

Comment: I built and loaded v4l2loopback as a kernel module and I cannot see v4l2loopback drive from flash as a camera (video device). I just see it with "lsmode". Otherwise, Flash does recognize VIVI driver..... ....

Comment: It works! Although the display is slow for 1280x1024 frames. It's OK for 640x480.

Answer (score 3):

Yes.

More generally, a device driver can allow as many simultaneous opens as it wants. Take a look at [Linux Device Drivers](http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-6-sect-6) for more info. You can use `filp->private_data` to store data relevant to the specific open instance.

For even more flexibility, a device driver isn't even limited to having a single device node in `/dev`.

Answer (score 1):

Can a driver be used by two program :

It usually can, but it is driver dependant. When it comes to data capture, you often have one process which gets all the data, and other processes have only limited access to the driver functionnality. So in the end, the API is ok with multiple process opening a driver, but in the end it all depends on the driver.

Can the VIVI driver be used as a bridge driver :

No. It is a video **capture** emulation driver, but there is no "video output" or "video sink" capability in this driver. You will have to understant why flash doesn't work with your real driver, but does work with a virtual driver. strace is your friend.

Comment: As far as I've understood, VIVI was built by using Video4Linux2 API, which is the base for most webcams' drivers on Linux. So I think if I achieve to feed a Video4Linux2 entity, i'll be able to display its images from Flash.

Comment: @Manel : Vivi generates the data that are made available via the V4L2 capture API. There is nothing in the driver that allow to feed data